# How to ensure the correct state of local variables when using BeginInvoke method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code:

```
string message;
while (balloonMessages.TryDequeue(out message))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Outside: {0}", message);
     BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Inside: {0}", message);
     });
}
```

It gives me this output:

```
Outside: some_message
Inside:
```

How can I ensure that some local variables will be passed to the `BeginInvoke` method as expected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may due to `access to modified closure`.

Comment: @X-TECH I agree but surely that'd only be true if balloonMessages last message was a null or empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a local copy:

```
string message;
while (balloonMessages.TryDequeue(out message))
{
     var localCopy = message;
     Console.WriteLine("Outside: {0}", localCopy);
     BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Inside: {0}", localCopy);
     });
}
```

This way, it will always be it's own variable for each loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
string message;
while (balloonMessages.TryDequeue(out message))
{
     var msg=message;
     Console.WriteLine("Outside: {0}", msg);
     BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Inside: {0}", msg);
     });
}
```

BeginInvoke does not run synchronously and the loop continues sometimes without executing the Console.Writeline statement, and the value in message variable changes. Declaring new variable ensures that the value is preserved for the beginInvoke method

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why

Comment: B/C BeginInvoke does not run synchronously and the loop continues sometimes without executing the Console.Writeline statement, and the value in message variable changes. Declaring new variable ensures that the value is preserved for the beginInvoke method